# Inkjet printing on platic covers

Tags: print-design

We are looking for an immediate drying ink for printing on plastic pouches/covers, can any body know the source?

Comment: I don't want to be blunt, but have you googled your question and contacted some printers or ink suppliers?

Answer (score 1):

You need a system that prints with "solvent" inks.

There are some newer systems too that use UV / latex & other processes.

However with very, very little detail in your question, this is as much help as I can give right now.